# Ajax post not working in window beforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onbeforeunload

i have multiple identical forms (one for each month) that sit on multiple sections using this script :

http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples

no problems there.

When i hit the next or previous buttons, i post the data on the form with this :

```js
var tsf = $('.tsf-wizard-1').tsfWizard({
                stepEffect: 'basic',
                stepStyle: 'style1',
     validation: false,
                navPosition: 'top',
                manySteps: true,
                stepTransition: true,
                showButtons: true,
                showStepNum: true,
                height: '500px',
                prevBtn: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> Vorige Maand',
                nextBtn: 'Volgende Maand <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>',
                finishBtn: '<i class="fa fa-table"></i> Overzicht', 
                onNextClick: function (e, from, to, validation) {
                 var stap = from+1;    
     var formstep = '#'+stap.toString()+'_form';
     var pathname = window.location.pathname; // Returns path only
     var url      = window.location.href;  
                    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'user_settings/add_data',
      data: $(formstep).serialize(),
      success: function () {
        console.log($(formstep).serialize());
      },
      error: function (){
         $( "#remarks").html("<span class=\"label label-danger\">ERROR !</span> Problem saving..");
      }
     });
                }, 
    onPrevClick: function (e, from, to, validation) {
                 var stap = from+1;    
     var formstep = '#'+stap.toString()+'_form';
                    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'user_settings/add_data',
      data: $(formstep).serialize(),
      success: function () {
       console.log($(formstep).serialize());
      },
      error: function (){
         $( "#remarks").html("<span class=\"label label-danger\">ERROR !</span> Problem saving..");
      }
     });
                }        
            });
```

But, when the user leaves the page i want to have all of the forms posted with an ajax call. So i tried this (The hold.open and .close is busy indicator)

```js
$(window).on('beforeunload', function ()
 {
  //this will work only for Chrome
  pageSave();
 });

 $(window).on("unload", function ()
 {
  //this will work for other browsers
  pageSave();
}); 



function pageSave()
 {
  if (!_wasPageSaved)
  {
   HoldOn.open({
     theme:'sk-cube-grid',
     message:"<h4>Savig data..</h4>"
    });
    var goodsaves=0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) { 
     var formstep = '#'+i.toString()+'_form';
     $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '<?php echo base_url();?>user_settings/add_data',
      data: $(formstep).serialize(),
      success: function () {
           goodsaves=goodsaves+1;
      },
      error: function (){
       console.log('error saving data :');
      }
     });
    }
   HoldOn.close();
   if (goodsaves=>11) {
    _wasPageSaved = true;
        console.log('all forms saved');
   }
        }
    }
```

Problem is that sometimes the data is saved, sometimes not. I can't put my finger on it why it doesn't always work . I see the busy indicator, i don't get any alerts in my console and the next page is loaded. But my data isn't saved...

hope anyone can clear this out , thanks allot in advance.

Comment: Look at the [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API).

Comment: `beforeunload` event is useful to prevent an unload from occuring, there is no guarantee that asynchronous requests can be made in the event handler - as previous comment suggests, use Beacon in browsers that support it, note that there is no response possible from a Beacon request either